# jQuery mobile tap event triggered for twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I tested with jquery mobile 'tap' event and found it fired **two times**, everytime it is triggered. Code as below for a html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>      
    <style>
        #box{
            background-color:red;
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
        }   
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        tapped me
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box').bind('tap',function(event) {
                alert('why');
            }); 
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

More irony is when I test this over jsfiddle, it only fired the event for **one time**.

Here's the link.
http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/tzQ6D/6/

After further testing I found out the bug has gone away with placing the javascript at header section.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js">
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #box{ background-color:red; width:200px; height:200px; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box').bind('tap', function(event) {
                alert('halo');
            });
        });
    </script>        
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
        tapped me
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I couldn't explained why the placement at the body and header section make this different.

Answer (score 15):

I forget where I saw this, but the issue is that jQuery Mobile is binding to both touch and mouse events in order to simulate "tap," and in some circumstances Android will fire both.

The trick that has worked for me is to call `preventDefault` on the event in your event handler. That will keep the duplicate event from firing.

As far as why this is the case only sometimes, I know that mobile browsers will try to only fire the mouse version of the event if someone isn't listening to the touch version. There may be an issue with detection or jQuery's delegation that is confusing that heuristic.

Comment: In the case where mouse events and touch events are firing, returning false in combination with preventDefault should fix it in most (maybe all) browsers.

Comment: Yes this seems to work for us too. I can confirm that, while using jquery mobile 1.4.2 we experienced this behavior, and putting e.preventDefault() resolved the issue for us.

Comment: It's amazing! In my case I put **e.preventDefault();** after all actions in  `$('.selector').on('click touchstart', function(e){})` function and magic happend. W/o **e.preventDefault();** touchstart event caused double click/tap. Thank you a lot, man!

Comment: this is working example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165360/touch-events-firing-twice

Answer (score 9):

You are experiencing the ghost click issue... It's a known "bug" and hard to resolve.

More infos there :

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/tap-fires-twice-with-live-tap
https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons
http://philosopherdeveloper.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/ghost-clicks-in-jquery-mobile/

In the first link you will find a hack that does the trick. As far as I know, there is no easy solution :(

BTW: Even if it won't solve your problem, @Sagiv is right. JQuery mobile often use ajax for changing page and so does not trigger a document.ready event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found out the issue is gone if I place the code at the header section. No idea why.

Answer (score 5):

from the [jQuery Mobile page](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html):

> **Important: Use $(document).bind('pageinit'), not $(document).ready()**
>   The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   $(document).ready() function so everything will execute as soon as the
>   DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the pageinit event.
>   This event is explained in detail at the bottom of this page.

so skip the `$(document).ready()`. more info [here](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Did a test with pageinit, the pageinit event was fired twice as well. I test on both firefox and chrome. Seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

related with this question, I was getting two events 'tap' and 'click' one just after the other one. All ideas here were inspiring, but I ended up finding another solution. I added the following code to my JavaScript controller to discriminate consecutive duplicated events based on the timestamp that, fortunately, is exactly the same for the two duplicated events. Basically, what I do is to store the last used timestamp if I decide to consume the event. The second time an event with the same timestamp I just discarded it.

```js
var _lastEventTimestamp;
var checkAndPreventDuplicatedEvent = function (e) {
    if (e.timeStamp === _lastEventTimestamp) return true;
    else _lastEventTimestamp = e.timeStamp;
    return false;
}
```

then, in each of my handlers I added this filtering code in the beginning:

```js
var onTapSomething = function (e) {
   if (checkAndPreventDuplicatedEvent(e)) return;        
   //do here whatever you would do in the case of legitimate event...   
}
```

Comment: one more, you can use the same strategy to also get rid of some "noise" events just in case. I was having some issues on android... that I get rid of by using this modified version of the previous filter:    var checkAndPreventDuplicatedEvent = function (e) {
        if ((e.timeStamp - _lastEventTimestamp)<1000) return true;
        else _lastEventTimestamp = e.timeStamp;
        return false;
    }

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#buttonID").tap(function(event){
        if(localStorage.JQMGostClick == 0 || localStorage.JQMGostClick == "" || typeof(localStorage.JQMGostClick) === "undefined")
            localStorage.JQMGostClick = 1;
        else if(localStorage.JQMGostClick == 1){
            localStorage.JQMGostClick = 0;
            return false;
        }
.....
});
```

It works for me, since if you are using a mobile environment then probably you are using a kind of storage

Answer (score 0):

I found out that in my case the addition of `data-role="page"` to my page container prevented tap events from being fired twice.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced something like this before and it was due to the fact that my form was not inside a `data-role="page"`

What I would suggest is to wrap your code with jQuery Mobile html structure so your could should look like this instead

```
<div data-role="page" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active">
  <div class="ui-content">
    <div id="box">
        tapped me
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#box').bind('tap',function(event) {
                alert('why');
            }); 
        });
    </script>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution and will only work in some cases but what worked for me was immediately after the click event starts set the CSS 'pointer-events' for that element to 'none'. Then using JS's setTimeout reset the 'pointer-events' to auto after 500ms.

For me 300ms was enough for Android devices but iPhone needed 500ms to prevent the double click.

```js
function yourEvent(evt){

  $(el).css('pointer-events', 'none');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(el).css('pointer-events', 'auto');
  }, 500);
  
  //do you stuff

}
```