# Android phonegap - click event is fired on the next screen

Tags: android, knockout.js, cordova

I'm using phonegap (cordova 2.8), and android 4.2.1,
I use as frame works: knockout, & jquery mobile.
The app is based on http://propertycross.com/jquery-mobile/

I get the following funny behavior:
when clicking on a button that moves to another screen #2,
if there is a button in #2 screen at the same location, 
then it get clicked as well...

The only solution I found is to wrap the code that change the screen with setTimeout:

```
            setTimeout(function() {
                application.navigateTo(viewModel);
            },600);
```

This solve the problem but slow down the app...

This is actually unfortunate since the phonegap is already too slow...

Thanks.

Comment: Is your click binding on mousebutton down, on mousebutton up, or just click?  Have you tried using on mousebutton up?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can do:

1) e.stopPropagation(), e.preventDefault()

phopkins describes this here:
[jQuery mobile tap event triggered for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794181/jquery-mobile-tap-event-triggered-for-twice)

I'll elaborate, as this was a major issue for me. This applies to any of the tap, click, vclick and probably other events.

Your event functions should have stopPropogation() and preventDefault() called, like so:

```
$('#selector').tap(function(e) {
    //your code here

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This helps, however, I found that you could still get the "phantom" click.

2) Bind the event to the page, not the button.

That way it's not bound to the next page.

For example, for a page with id='myPage' and a button with id='myBtn':

```
$('#myPage').on('tap', '#myBtn', function(e) {
    //your code here

    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();

});
```