# touchend event gets triggered twice

Tags: javascript

This is my code in case `touchend` event occurs:

```
$('body').on('click touchend', '.typeSelect', function(){
    var Classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
    var width1 = $(this).width();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.typeDropDownList').hide();
    $('.'+Classes[0]+'List').css({'width' : width1+12}).toggle();
});
```

If the event is `click`, everything works fine, but if it's `touchend`, this function gets called twice. Why is that?

Comment: what happens when you do `touchend` only - `$('body').on('touchend', `

Comment: Mobile browsers trigger both `click` and `touchend`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [touch events firing twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165360/touch-events-firing-twice)

Comment: @gurvinder372 Same, triggers twice

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze Link shared by RogerC talks about the same issue as well. Is it possible for you to create a working snippet to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I know about this question, answers did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off click if event type is touchend

```
 $('body').on('click touchend', '.typeSelect', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault();
        if(e.type == 'touchend'){
            $(this).off('click');
        }
    var Classes = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
        var width1 = $(this).width();
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.typeDropDownList').hide();
        $('.'+Classes[0]+'List').css({'width' : width1+12}).toggle();
    });
```

Comment: Does not work. I have tried this method before I posted my question.

Comment: @VaxoBasilidze please approve the answer and upvote if it had helped you