# Pass header script to AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

As I googled the information, the ajax load in jquerymobile (JQM) doesn't contain the header javascripts. Reference topics are as follow:

[jQuery mobile tap event triggered for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794181/jquery-mobile-tap-event-triggered-for-twice)

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

I would like to know how the ajax content can include the header scripts.

My example scripts (not real script) is

**In index.php**

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script-test.js"></script>
</header>

<div id="id<?php echo $product['product_id'] ?>">
    Content<?php echo $product['product_id'] ?>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
 ajaxload content scripts
//--></script>
```

**In index-ajax.php**

```
<div id="id<?php echo $product['product_id'] ?>">
 Content<?php echo $product['product_id'] ?>
</div>
```

**I've tried to manually add  to index-ajax.html. However, it will trigger the error (load 2 times of the js) to other contents which is not inside the ajax.

Comment: Your `php` opening tags are wrong. It should be `<?php` not `<php`.

Comment: there is no way you can name your files (index.html, index-ajax.html) and be able to run PHP code inside them. they need to renamed to (index.php, index-ajax.php) if you mix HTML with PHP the file names need to have the (.php) extension so the webserver picks up on the fact page has PHP code inside it

Comment: @Tasos Thanks and I've refined the description

Answer (score 1):

According to [jQuery Mobile FAQ: Why aren't my scripts and styles loading?](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/faq/scripts-and-styles-not-loading.html)

> The reason that the head of a page is ignored when requested via AJAX is that the potential of re-executing the same JavaScript is very high (it's common to reference the same scripts in every page of a site). Due to the complexity of attempting to work around that issue, we leave the task of executing page-specific scripts to the developer, and assume head scripts are only expected to execute once per browsing session.

You will either need to have the script tied in some way to the `pageinit` event or you could include that in the `data-role="page"` but this will execute each time the page is loaded.

I would definitely advise to re-factor your code and have this based on the `pageinit` event.