# JQuery alert popups three times but executed once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have added alert when the img div is tapped. I am getting multiple alerts for single tap. On web interface sometimes I am getting single alert but on mobile its executing multiple times. And the tap event is not working for the first tap. It is working for second tap.

```
<html>
<body>
plug:<img id="plug" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/zeusbox/gartoon/32/socket-icon.png">
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.5.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.5.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#plug").on('tap', function() {
      alert("plese long press");
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: why is your script outside the `html` tag?

Comment: is that is the problem?

Comment: Not entirely but, some browsers might ignore your scripts because this is a malformed document

Comment: okay I changed that but I am getting alert multiple times only

Comment: Try `$("#plug").off("tap").on('tap', function() {...`

Comment: Same problem is occuring  @Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error in console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

i think your JQuery version and JQuery-ui version not compatible.

change your jquery-ui with this one

    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

that should solve the problem
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this..

```
$("#plug").on('tap', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("plese long press");
});
```

According to this it has worked for others: [jQuery mobile tap event triggered for twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794181/jquery-mobile-tap-event-triggered-for-twice)

Answer (score 0):

In your event add a `preventDefault()` to stop the event firing more than once:

```
$("#plug").unbind('tap').on('tap', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("please long press"); 
});
```

Comment: But it is again invoking three times. And the tap event is working for the second tap in mobile version.

Comment: Ok, add an unbind call chained in to the binding of the tap event.